# serialize Django object and related objects

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

This is the model I use:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(A)

class D models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I want to select one A object and all its related B, C, D objects to serialize in json. Serializing is fine but how could I select A and related objects?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.FOO_set`-manager:

```
var a = A.objects.get(id)
var b = a.b_set.all() # All related B objects to a
var c = a.c_set.all() # All related C objects to a
...etc
```